# Need help in understanding the procedure of expanding recurrence formula

Tags: recurrence-relations

So here is the actual expansion:

\begin{align}
T(n) &= T(n-1) + n \\
&= T(n-2) + (n-1) + n \\
&= T(n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n \\
&\vdots \\
&= T(0) + 1 + 2 + \ldots + (n-2) + (n-1) + n \\
&= T(0) + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = O(n^2) 
\end{align}

I do not understand how it is being done. Like how we got second line from the first line. Recurrence is really confusing for me. Hope you can explain it! Thank you!

Comment: You know that $T(m)=T(m-1)+m$. Now set $m=n-1$. What do you get when you replace $m$ by $n-1$ in the expression $T(m)=T(m-1)+m$?

Comment: I get $T(n-1) = T(n-2) + (n-1)$ So then I just plug it in the formula at the first line for T(n-1), right? Thanks!

Comment: That's right.${}$